# How to pass extra data and check if token is valid with JWT

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt

I just started a project where I have to use Node + few things related to it and I feel a little confused!
I use JWT for authentication, particularly I created my project like this:

```
api
 |---teams
      |----teams.controller.js
      |----teams.router.js
      |----teams.service.js
 |---users (same as team)
auth
 |---token_validation.js
other things
 |---other things
```

I use **token_validation.js** for JWT to validate user while login and seems it work (verified with Postman)

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = {
  checkToken: (req, res, next) => {
    let token = req.get("authorization");
    if (token) {
      // Remove Bearer from string
      token = token.slice(7);
      jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("err: " + err);
          return res.json({
            success: 0,
            message: "Invalid Token..."
          });
        } else {
          req.decoded = decoded;
          next();
        }
      });
    } else {
      // other code
    }
  }
};
```

I need to insert a new team in DB (MariaDB) and user can create a new team after login. My problem is that while using Session in Java for e.g. I can easly set extras like username of the logged in user and when I need to know what's the username of the logged in user is, I can take it from session

```
String username = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
```

I can't understand how to do the same with Node/JWT. What I need to do is, after login I need to save the user_id and when user crate a new team I need to send to DB the user_id with other data (if token still valid).

```
const {
    create
} = require("./teams.service");

module.exports = {
    createTeam: (req, res) => {
        const body = req.body;

       // here I need to check if token still valid
       // if yes -> take user id and send it to DB with
       // other data

        create(body, (err, results) => {
          if (err) {  // if fails
            // handle
          }
          return res.status(200).json({ // success
            success: 1,
            data: results
          });
        });
    },
}
```

I thought I could add it in **user.controller.js** when user login:

```
    if (result) {
            results.password = undefined; 
            const jsontoken = sign({ result: results }, process.env.JWT_KEY, {
              expiresIn: "1h",
              user_id: get somehow //error
            });
   // other code
   }
```

but it gives me an error, tells me like I can't add user_id to sign. Can anyone please tell me the right way to store and get this kind of data and use them when needed while user still have a valid token to stay logged in?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your data to the options, not the payload.

```
    if (result) {
            results.password = undefined;
            results.user_id = XXXXXXXX //get somehow

            const jsontoken = sign({ result: results }, process.env.JWT_KEY, {
              expiresIn: "1h"
            });
      ...
   }
```

Comment: If I do like this, var userId = result.user_id; How can i get this var after login when needed?

Comment: see `jwt.verify`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to set it in localStorage. When you make a req to backend send it with headers, then in backend check if token is valid and send response with data that you want.